# Почему предложный падеж "в забытьИ"?

Tags: падежи, окончания

Ружьё, сырьё, мытьё — о (в) ружь**е**, сырь**е**, мыть**е**; но *забытьё — в забыть**и***. Почему так?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь исторически разные случаи. **Забытьё** получилось в результате фонетического изменения конечного -ИЕ (не Ё - ср. *бытие, житие*). Образует падежные формы по церковнославянской модели существительных на ***-ие***. **Ружьё** же и все прочее образовалось уже на русской почве и непосредственному влиянию ЦСЯ не подвергалось.

Comment: Спасибо! Но всё-таки житие, бытие — о житиИ, бытиИ, но житьё, бытьё — о житьЕ, бытьЕ. Здесь вот не сохраняется форма от -ие.

Comment: *но житьё, бытьё — о житьЕ, бытьЕ* - это разговорные формы, мы же не о них сейчас?!

Comment: А-а, действительно, даже не подумал, что разговорные и что это определяет.

Comment: А "забытие" было с ударением на Ы и то же означало, что и "забытьё", или и это, и что-то ещё (может, процесс забывания тоже)?